# JBoss 5.1.0.GA doesn't see latest classes versions

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I deployed my EAR application many times in spree on JBoss 5.1.0.GA, and the restarted server. The result is that JBoss seem not to see latest versions of particular classes. Just like they had been cached. Uninstall application, further clean restart and redeploying doesn't make any difference.

How can I fix it? Maybe purge somehow JVM memory (Java 1.6)? I would be grateful for any help or hints.

Comment: Are these your classes or some libraries you are using?

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the work, log and temp folders under the server mode (default/all/minimal etc) you are running the application on. Then deploy the application.
However re-deploying an application does not need to do the above steps. try it out though.

Comment: i tried it. i have shell script to do it on every server's startup